# How to loop through checkboxes in top to bottom design order, or set order

Tags: c#

I have this code so far:

```
foreach (Control child in TableNamePanel.Controls)
{
    if (!(child is CheckBox))
       continue;

    if ((child as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        Code... 
    }
}
```

My design has the `CheckBoxes` on top of each other and the other does matter. I would like to check the first `checkbox`, then the next and so on. Currently it's starting from the bottom. Any way to change that, or to set the order of how it loops through the control items?

Comment: is it windows form ?

Comment: The controls are in the same order as they're added in the designer.cs file.

Comment: You can use LINQ `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` to order the controls by a specific property.

Comment: side note:there is no need to safe cast. you can do direct cast `(CheckBox)child`. because of if statement `!(child is CheckBox)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `foreach` like this:

```
foreach (Control child in TableNamePanel.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
}
```

This will sort `Controls` as per `TabIndex` in the form. You might need to change `OrderBy` to `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 4):

I think when you loop through they are in order according to they are in desing

but they are not than you can set `CheckBox.TabIndex` property on checkbox to order it

```
var orderedcheckbox= TableNamePanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                       .OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex);
```

Here I assumeed that tabindex property is avaialbe as per my knowledge this property is available in .net.

---

Including other solution suggested in comment by @dotNET

TabOrder of your controls at design-time, which he should have anyway. The other way around could be to use the Location property of your checkboxes instead of TabOrder in the above code.

Comment: This is a good solution, but presumably OP has already set `TabOrder` of your controls at design-time, which he should have anyway. The other way around could be to use the `Location` property of your checkboxes instead of TabOrder in the above code.